# jQuery: Add fade effect to replace attr

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add a fade effect when using replace() to change image attributes? I have a code that uses a button to switch every image on the site to an alternate version (by changing the path of the image); I wanted each image to fade to its alternate version.

Here is the code:

```
$('.imgbutton').click(function() {
   $('img').attr("src",function(index,attr){
    return attr.replace("directory1/","directory2/");
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a combo of `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` you can make this work:

```
$('.imgbutton').click(function() {
    $('img').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr("src",function(index,attr) {
            return attr.replace("directory1/","directory2/");
        }).fadeIn();
    });
});
```